# Arduino | RGB LED Strip Controller

Tags: c++, arduino, rgb, microcontroller, led

I have an Arduino UNO and I am attempting to turn ON and OFF a color (red, green, or blue) light of the strip. Here is my code, but All the lights remain lit. The issue is that for example I might want to only show the color RED, but I can't seem to get any of the colors to turn off. I have the pins as follows:

- RED: 5
- GREEN: 6
- BLUE: 3

My setup:
[image]

Default controller photo:
[image]

Relevant Code:

```
int ledPinR = 5;
int ledPinG = 6;
int ledPinB = 3;

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPinR, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPinG, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPinB, OUTPUT);
}
void loop()  {
  analogWrite(ledPinR, 0);
  analogWrite(ledPinG, 0);
  analogWrite(ledPinB, 0);
}
```

Comment: @MikeCAT wow! That was fast! Is the code correct for turning the strip off

Comment: What strip do you have?

Comment: @djUniversal `SMD RGB 5050 Waterproof LED Strip light`

Comment: What are pins 3,5 and 6 connected to? Is there a controller chip? The only thing I can find with that name is an led strip with a remote control. No data sheet?

Comment: What @djUniversal was trying to say: Is it an analog strip? (4 connectors: R, G, B and GND) Or a digital strip? (3 connectors: VCC, DATA, GND). Also: Did you connect both grounds? (strip and arduino?) In the event is is digital: What controller chip? WS2811? (==WS2812 LEDs, which have a WS2811 integrated)

Comment: @djUniversal They are analog R G B GND. No Controller. Just the Arduino. I have the Arduino connected to the computer via USB and to the vall with a 12v power adapter.

Comment: @showp1984 They are analog R G B GND. No Controller. Just the Arduino. I have the Arduino connected to the computer via USB and to the vall with a 12v power adapter.

Comment: What happens when you physically remove one or more of the wires from the Arduino pins?

Comment: @djUniversal Removing 12v = strip powers off. Removing Red = red turns off. Removing Blue = blue turns off. Removing Green = green turns off.

Comment: For an analog strip @Secko has the answer for you.

Comment: @showp1984 The Led strip continues to stay on. No change

Comment: Have you tried driving the lines with digitalWrite to see if they will just turn on/off the individual lines? Also, without seeing a data sheet are they supposed to be driven with a low logic level not high?

Comment: @djUniversal I really can't answer that. I can open the provided power supply/controller if that would help.

Comment: Do you have a link to where you bought it?

Comment: @djUniversal http://www.ebay.com/itm/2-5M-SMD-RGB-5050-Waterproof-LED-Strip-light-300-44-Key-Remote-12V-Supply-Power/381465433704

Comment: Do you have a remote with it? Does it change the colour?

Comment: @djUniversal Yes and Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood my last comment under @Secko's answer, so here is what I meant:

```
int r = 5;
int g = 6;
int b = 3;

void setup() {
    pinMode(r, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(g, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(b, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    analogWrite(r, 128);
    delay(50);
    analogWrite(r, 0);
    analogWrite(g, 128);
    delay(50);
    analogWrite(g, 0);
    analogWrite(b, 128);
    delay(50);
    analogWrite(b, 0);
    delay(50);
}
```

You need to turn off the last color you turned on in order to get a red, green and blue blink light. Otherwise if you turn on green after red, the strip will be yellow for a short time. If you then turn on blue it will be white and stay white, since no colors are ever turned off.

The second parameter is the voltage applied to your pins. It ranges from 0 - 255, where 0 is 0V and 255 is 5V. 128 is right in the middle with 2.5V.

If your strip is large (=>3 LEDs with power efficient LEDs. Otherwise >1), I hope you use transistors to offload the current draw from the arduino to the transistor. Otherwise you will blow the arduino very soon.

**EDIT:**
You probably blew the arduino already by pulling too much current (too much LEDs) from it's pins.

You will need a PNP transistor in between each color and the arduino that can handle a large current (since you drive a lot of LEDs), which means a darlington transistor array integrated circuit.

Something like the TIP125 comes to mind. (https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/TI/TIP125.pdf)

It has a maximum collector current of 5A. Put this right in the middle of your VCC and the strip (VCC to collector, the strip to emitter) and connect the arduino to the base of the transistor. You will need 3, one for each color.

**EDIT2:**
Here is a very quickly made schematic to show you the basics. It should be fully functional for a 12V LED strip with an individual color current draw of up to 5A (so 15A total).

You may want to add resistors on the transistor base to sink current though.

[image: tip125/arduino transistor schematic]

**EDIT3:**
Since you are probably new to electronics: A PNP transistor will enable the connection between collector and emitter if the base is low. Meaning: `analogWrite(r, 0)` will turn the color on the strip on and `analogWrite(r, 255)` will turn it off. It is inverted with the transistor in between.

Also, and I hope this is obvious, **DO NOT ROUTE 5A PER COLOR THROUGH A BREADBOARD OR THROUGH TINY WIRES. THEY WILL GO UP IN SMOKE.**

Comment: Red, Green, Blue in rapid succession.

Comment: Just the single color? Ex when red goes on, all others are off?

Comment: Yes. It's basically a red, green and blue blink light with no dark pauses in between.

Comment: It still won't do it. No matter what I try every color (no matter dimmed or not) will always stay on.

Comment: How large is your strip? I Have this code running in front of me right now, working perfectly for a single LED. So either you blew the arduino already by pulling too much current (too much LEDs), or the strip has a different method of interacting with the controller. How is it connected? Directly? Did you connect GND from the strip to the arduino?

Comment: If you like, I could provide a picture.

Comment: I added the photo to the post.

Comment: With that connection (direct) you probably blew the pins on the arduino you have used to connect RED, GREEN and BLUE. Test them with a multimeter or a single LED and digitalWrite to see if you blew them.

Comment: That's alright, I have another. How can I fix this connection?

Comment: I updated my answer to explain a simple transistor circuit.

Comment: What about a [L7805CV](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/STMicroelectronics/L7805CV/?qs=9NrABl3fj%2FqplZAHiYUxWg%3D%3D)

Comment: That's not a transistor, it is a voltage regulator and only capable of 5V regulation.

Comment: Chances? It will work if the strip is indeed high powered. Meaning: R G B GND. If it's R G B VCC you will need a TIP120. Both are capable of up to 5A and 60V max. See my last edit, which adds a picture.
The rest is up to you :)

Comment: One last thing! Haha. It has R G B 12V

Comment: Then you will be fine with the schematic I added to my answer and the tip125. ;) I recommend you read a bit about PNP and NPN transitors and in general though ^^

Comment: Does the 12V line correspond to the TIP120 or the TIP125? Sorry! :D

Comment: Have you even looked at the schematic :( it shows you your situation exactly and even has the part numbers on it :(

Comment: Alright! Sorry. Thank you so much for your help! I'll be sure to place an order in for those TIP125's. Have a wonderful night!

Comment: @NicholasJohnson no problem, and it's a wonderful morning since it's 4:15AM here :) Good night to you and please accept the answer.

Comment: Alright I just did. Also, I just looked and said "Wait that wasn't on his post."..... I forgot to reload the answer (*_*)

Comment: i just got those transistors. Hooked everything up on DIFFERENT PWM pins, and no difference.

Comment: Then you did something wrong (wiring) or provided wrong information (EG: strip is being controlled differently). As stated previously: For a 12V LED strip with R G B high (12V) and the 4th Channel low (GND) the TIP125 has to work with the above schematic and an inverted logic. If it's R G B low (GND) and the 4th channel is high (12V) the TIP120 is needed with slightly different connection wiring (it will sit in the same spot but will switch GND instead of VCC) and no invertion of the logic. If needed I can hook it up here for a GND switched 'strip' and make some pics & a video.

Comment: Alrighty. How can I go about finding out whether it's gnd or vcc? (This company has no schematics! Sorry!)

Comment: Use a voltmeter. Connect the original controller and set it to white at maximum brightness. Then measure between any color and the 4th wire. If you get a negative value, switch the voltmeter leads. If you get a positive value, then the red voltmeter lead measures VCC and the black GND. Or: take a !regulated! 12V 2A PSU and connect it to one color and the 4th wire. Since LEDs are diodes they will only light up in one direction, giving you the polarity as well.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add pinMode() to setup.

```
void setup() {
    pinMode(ledPinR, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPinG, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPinB, OUTPUT);
}
```

Comment: Even upon doing that, still doesn't turn the strip off

Answer (score 0):

You have to delay the operations, before your turn the next light on or off like so:

EDIT: a complete fader for your case, you might want to skip 4 in the loop, but I will let you handle that.

```
int ledPinR = 5;
int ledPinG = 6;
int ledPinB = 3;

int brightness = 0;
int fade = 5;

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPinR, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPinG, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPinB, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  for(int LED_PIN = 3; LED_PIN<=6; LED_PIN++) {
    analogWrite(LED_PIN, brightness); //setting the brightness at LED pin
    brightness += fade; //brightness increasE
    if(brightness == 0 || brightness == 255){
      fade = -fade;
    }
    delay(30); //time of delay is in miliseconds
  }
}
```

EDIT2: OK, saw your setup, I was way off on what you wanted to do with the colors, don't know if I should delete the answer, it is misguiding now. Hope the delay helped though.

Comment: The Led strip continues to stay on. No change. Sorry to be a hassle! Lol

Comment: @NicholasJohnson This will only power them up one-by-one on the first powerup. After that they will stay lit. You have to turn the color off again after the delay if you want only one color to cycle through the strip.

Comment: Well, you have to fade it out or change the brightness value (it is 0 now), but I thought you already knew that.

Comment: @Secko It seems to tint it. If i set the red value to 0, then the rest to 0. It produces a pink color

Comment: @showp1984 no matter if I set the value to 0 or 255 it is still lit.

Comment: @NicholasJohnson see me answer which contains the information of my last comment which you apparently misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. My issue was that I was inverting the Emitter and Collector wiring at the transistor.

For the TIP125 transistor suggested by **showp1984**, you'll want to make sure that the LED strip is connected to the Emitter pin and the Collector pin must be connected to Arduino GND. Connect the Base of the transistor to the Arduino output pin (See below). Use a 1K Ohm resister to make the Base connection.

### Here is my setup:

- 3x Transistor TIP125 Darlington
- 1x Arduino Nano
- 1x 12V LED Strip
- 3x 1KiloOhm Resistors

### Wiring

[image: TIP125 Datasheet]

Use one transistor for each LED color (R, G, B):

***RED***

- Transistor Base --> RESISTOR --> Arduino PIN D5
- Transistor Collector --> Arduino GND
- Transistor Emitter --> LED Red

***GREEN***

- Transistor Base --> RESISTOR --> Arduino PIN D6
- Transistor Collector --> Arduino GND
- Transistor Emitter --> LED Green

***BLUE***

- Transistor Base --> RESISTOR --> Arduino PIN D3
- Transistor Collector --> Arduino GND
- Transistor Emitter --> LED Blue

### Code

```
// color swirl! connect an RGB LED to the PWM pins as indicated
// in the #defines
// public domain, enjoy!
 
#define REDPIN 5
#define GREENPIN 6
#define BLUEPIN 3
 
#define FADESPEED 5     // make this higher to slow down
 
void setup() {
  pinMode(REDPIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(GREENPIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BLUEPIN, OUTPUT);
  
}
 
 
void loop() {
  int r, g, b;

  // fade from blue to violet
  for (r = 0; r < 256; r++) { 
    analogWrite(REDPIN, r);
    delay(FADESPEED);
  } 
  // fade from violet to red
  for (b = 255; b > 0; b--) { 
    analogWrite(BLUEPIN, b);
    delay(FADESPEED);
  } 
  // fade from red to yellow
  for (g = 0; g < 256; g++) { 
    analogWrite(GREENPIN, g);
    delay(FADESPEED);
  } 
  // fade from yellow to green
  for (r = 255; r > 0; r--) { 
    analogWrite(REDPIN, r);
    delay(FADESPEED);
  } 
  // fade from green to teal
  for (b = 0; b < 256; b++) { 
    analogWrite(BLUEPIN, b);
    delay(FADESPEED);
  } 
  // fade from teal to blue
  for (g = 255; g > 0; g--) { 
    analogWrite(GREENPIN, g);
    delay(FADESPEED);
  } 

 
}
```

### Observations

Here are some more hurdles that I came across and took me some time to figure out.

#### Inverted values

- While using the TIP125, you actually need to set your output PIN to 255 to shut that PIN down and set it to 0 in order to bring it up:

```
 analogWrite(REDPIN, 255); //RED is off
 analogWrite(REDPIN, 0); //RED is on
```

#### Short at the transistor heatsink

This might sound obvious, but it cost me several hours. I was testing this setup on a breadboard and two of the three transistor heatsinks were leaning backwards just enough as to make light contact with the resistor legs. This was actually one of the main causes for the LEDs connected to these transistors to light up unexpectedly...